# Defining My Own Display Environment

Tags: environments

I would like to define an environment for displaying content, similar to display math mode or perhaps resembling the `figure` environment.

I can get as far as centring the contents as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newenvironment{displayme}{\begin{center}}{\end{center}}

\begin{document}

Hello there!

\begin{displayme}
  Hi
\end{displayme}

Hi!

\end{document}
```

But of course display math mode adds nice spacing around the equation with (I think) `abovedisplayskip` and `belowdisplayskip` but I'm not sure exactly how display math mode is defined and what values it uses where and so on and so forth.

Can it be replicated?

Comment: the standard latex text display environments such as center, quote etc already add vertical space (topsep or partpsep, depending) do you need your environment to us ethe math settings abovedisplayskip ?

Answer (score 2):

You can define `displayme` to be similar to `\[`...`\]` but also put its contents inside a `tabular`. The result is that the display will be in text mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{displayme}
  {\[
     \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}}
  {  \end{tabular}
   \]}

\begin{document}

Hello there!
\begin{displayme}
  Hi
\end{displayme}
Hi!

\end{document}
```

Note: Display math equations should form part of your paragraph style/flow and therefore should form part of the sentence structure. As such, it's rare to have it preceded by a blank line.