# How do display text like an equation

Tags: environments

How can I define a new environment `displaytext` so that the following two examples produce the same output?

First example :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\text{Displayed text}\]

\end{document}
```

Second example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaytext}
  Displayed text
\end{displaytext}

\end{document}
```

Basically I don't know how to separate the `\text` command into a separate beginning and end. Of course, the equation part can be separated using `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}`.

This would be useful to me because texmaker displays the first version like this : 
[image: this]

(It turns everything green inside the math environment, which is annoying, especially if the displayed text involves an inline equation.)

Comment: Are you familiar with the `center` environment?

Comment: @Mico Yes but I like the spacing from this method.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448726/defining-my-own-display-environment